# Swift Expected Declaration Error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

```
import UIKit

class ImageAnimation: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var IMGs: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        IMGs.animationImages = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG1.jpg"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG2.jpg"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG3.jpg"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG4.jpg")]
        IMGs.animationDuration = 1.0
        IMGs.animationRepeatCount = 25
        IMGs.startAnimating()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I get Expected Declaration (Error) at "override func viewDidLoad() {"
How to fix this problem

Comment: I have copied your code into an Xcode 9.1 iOS project and it compiled without problems.

Comment: I have XCode 9.0 and the code is compiling in it as well. I guess you need to include more details.

Answer (score 1):

try to clean project and compile again. to do that hit `⌘ + Shift + K`.
 or
`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` from command line.